# Understanding memory leaks in Chrome and the 'Uncovering DOM leaks' example

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, memory-leaks, profiling

On [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks) of the Chrome docs, they give this code example:

```
function start()
{
    var p = document.getElementById("p");
    detached = document.createElement("div");
    p.appendChild(detached);
    p.removeChild(detached);
    //Fill up detached with a bunch of garbage data
}
```

They then claim that this leaks because

> ..a DOM node is detached from the tree, but it still holds DOM wrapper objects that reference script data, effectively preventing the data from being collected.

This makes no sense to me.

1. Isn't the issue just that `detached` is still referenced by the script *(since it's a closure)*?  Shouldn't `detached = null` be enough to allow the GC to collect `detached` and remove the leak?
2. Why would `p` still hold a reference to `detached` if it's been removed?  If (1) is true, shouldn't

   ```
   p.appendChild(detached);
   p.removeChild(detached);
   ```

   do nothing at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's badly written documentation. The sentence would make sense if the `fill()` method once referenced global objects (e.g. `fill2()`) so I suspect the example code changed at some point.

`detached = null` will resolve the memory leak as per the following example.

```
function start()
{
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  detached = document.createElement("div");
  p.appendChild(detached);
  p.removeChild(detached);
  fill();
}

function fix()
{
  detached = null;
}

function fill()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.data = new Array(10000);
    for (var j = 0, l = div.data.length; j < l; ++j)
      div.data[j] = j.toString();
    detached.appendChild(div);
  }
}

function fill2()
{
  window.data = new Array(10000);
  for (var j = 0, l = window.data.length; j < l; ++j)
    window.data[j] = j.toString();

  for (var i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.data = window.data;
    detached.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```